# Find JAVA_HOME and set it on RHEL

Tags: java, linux

I had installed java a while ago on my RHEL machine. Now, I'm trying to run a program that requires the `JAVA_HOME` variable to be set. What is the best way to figure out the installation directory of my java installation and then set `JAVA_HOME`? Here are the results of running `java- version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have a `/usr/lib/jvm` directory, but it is empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, try `echo $JAVA_HOME` from the command line.  Since `java` is on your path already, `JAVA_HOME` may be set.

> What is the best way to figure out the installation directory of my java installation

Running the command `which java` will point you to where `java` is installed.

> and then set JAVA_HOME

You can edit `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `/etc/profile` to set `JAVA_HOME`.  Setting it in `~/etc/profile` will set it system wide, and this is probably not what you want.  Say for the sake of example the output of `which java` is `/opt/jdk_1.7.0_25`, then you'd just add `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk_1.7.0_25` to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and then run `source ~/.bashrc` (or `source ~/.bash_profile` if you set it there).

Note that in this case, `java` is on the `PATH` but in some cases you'd need to add `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` to add the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the `PATH`.

Comment: which java gives me: /usr/bin/java. However, when I try to browse to this folder, it doesn't exist. I can find /usr/bin but there is no java inside it.

Comment: Often `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to the `java` binary somewhere else on the filesystem.  There's no `java` utility if you run `ls -l` in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Ok, I set - export JAVA_HOME=/usr and the program I was trying to run (pig) worked (it was appending a /bin/java in the script). So, it works now, but setting it to /usr doesn't seem right to me.. let me know if this is dangerous or any thing

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.  I'd try to open a terminal and `cd /usr/bin`.  Then run `ls -l | grep java` which should show where `/usr/bin/java` points to.  You'll want that to be your `JAVA_HOME`.  I don't think what you have is dangerous, but it could cause problems for things that use `JAVA_HOME` to find other things, like `javac` that may or may not have links to them in `/usr/bin`

Comment: You can also locate the java binary by running `readlink -f $(which java))`. This works great for creating the JAVA_HOME environment variable based on java (in path):
`export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))`.
Credit to: [How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable automatically on Linux](http://ask.xmodulo.com/set-java_home-environment-variable-linux.html)

Answer (score 34):

RHEL uses alternatives subsystem to manage java installations. You can have
multiple versions of java installed, but only one is active at a time.

This means that running `which java` doesn't provide useful information. The
output would be the same no matter which java installation is selected via
alternatives. Running `readlink -f $(which java)` (as already suggested in
other comment) or using asking alternatives `alternatives --display java` would
be better.

See example from RHEL 6 machine with OpenJDK installed (which is shipped with
RHEL):

```
[root@example ~]# which java
/usr/bin/java
[root@example ~]# readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre/bin/java
[root@example ~]# alternatives --display java | head -2
java - status is manual.
 link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

Note that enviroment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not defined anywhere by default,
you would need to define it yourself in `.bashrc` of user which requires it.

In previous example, correct value of `JAVA_HOME` would be
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64`.

See details in [Install OpenJDK](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/Install_OpenJDK_on_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux.html)
documentation, search for section "Optional: Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable".

Answer (score 12):

`readlink` command will show you full path of symbolic link:

```
readlink -f `which java`
```

Answer (score 6):

The best you can do is avoid Red Hat's java altogether.

Get your java from Oracle and put it in /opt.
Then just create symlink /opt/java -> /opt/jdk-someversion, and create /etc/profile.d/java.sh containing

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then, to change system-wide java, just change symlink in opt.
To use multiple java versions, use scripts like the above with appropriate JAVA_HOME.

Furthermore, /sbin/service script used to run /etc/init.d scripts will rip off environment variables - executes env -i explicitly. So i.e. your tomcat will not get JAVA_HOME, you'll have to create setenv.sh in $CATALINA_BASE/bin.

Drawback to this approach is you don't get java updates from Red Hat.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to combine the above so that I can programmaticly set `JAVA_HOME`.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))|sed 's^jre/bin^^')
```

On Ubuntu, returns /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/.
On CentOS7, returns /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64/.

This can be added to a Makefile with

```
JAVA_HOME = $(shell dirname $$(readlink -f $$(which java))|sed 's^jre/bin^^')
```

This is much safer than exporting a hardcoded path and is more portable.

Answer (score 3):

At least on RHEL 7, `alternatives` sets up a slave link for `java_sdk` at:

`/etc/alternatives/java_sdk/`

This is a symlink to the root of the SDK installation.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked to change link in

/etc/alternatives for:

```
java -> /app/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/bin/java
```

I know this is old java, but this server was neglected in our company.