# Is there an official, "correct" way to define JAVA_HOME on RedHat systems with OpenJDK?

Tags: java, centos, redhat, fedora, java-home

As do many others, RedHat systems and their derivations, such as CentOS and Fedora, use the `alternatives` mechanism to support the use of different major versions of OpenJDK. This results in there being many candidates as the value for the JAVA_HOME environment variable, such as:

- `/etc/alternatives/jre`
- `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk`
- `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.x.0`
- `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_openjdk`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/java`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.x.0`

Is any of these to be considered the official, standard choice? Note that I'm aware of the difference between choices that do or do not include the Java version in their name. I also consciously omitted names that include minor version information, as they would need to be modified after each update.

By the way, all of the above are symbolic links. The actual installation directories are found in `/usr/lib/jvm` and include the specific version in their name. e.g. `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-0.b11.el6_9.x86_64`.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I am not so sure as I am on Windows right now, but if you install the JRE, do some of the symlinks change?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the use case / your personal usage, e.g. by default I would point the `JAVA_HOME` to the current `JRE` (I think that was `/etc/alternatives/jre`)

On my development machine I may let it point to the current `SDK`.

Maybe all my deployed software relies on some specific java version, so I point the `JAVA_HOME` to that installation version.

***In most cases*** I don't want to set it at all. Rather I want programs to fail as I didn't specify which variant I want to use.

Clearly not the answer to "which is the official standard choice", but I think that might help too. Additionally that is clearly my opinion and it was too long for a comment.

The following may also be interesting:

- [Find JAVA_HOME and set it on RHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290554/find-java-home-and-set-it-on-rhel) (which contains [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590995/6202869) pointing to: [JBoss EAP Installation Guide - Install OpenJDK](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/installation_guide/install_openjdk_on_red_hat_enterprise_linux) which also mentions setting `JAVA_HOME`, but leaves it open, which one you should use. It just mentions the path where it might be installed)